# How can I prevent \u001Bc from clearing the screen in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am using a CLI application that prints `\u001Bc` to the terminal to clear the screen. This application is not interactive, though, and I would like to see all of its output. Is there a way to prevent this application from clearing the screen without altering its source code?

I attempted to use `app | grep -v '\u001Bc'` but this doesn't appear to work, and it would also filter out the entire line containing `\u001Bc` even if it did work.

Comment: `echo -e '\u001Bc' | tr -d '\u001Bc'`?

Comment: I was actually just trying that very thing! It works for the echo example, but for some reason it's not working as part of an npm script.

Comment: Show its output in your question: `app | hexdump -C`

Comment: Got it! I needed a double escape because json: `"app | tr -d \"\\u001bc\""`

Comment: @Cyrus if you post an answer I can go ahead and accept it :)

Comment: @Cyrus: Are you sure `tr` understands `\u` codes? Are you sure it can remove a combination of two characters, `Esc + c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the <kbd>Esc + c</kbd> via sed

```
application | sed 's/\x1bc//g'
```